# How can a Tcl procedure access dozens of constants outside it?

Tags: tcl

A tcl script has dozens of procedures and is used to aid in debug of a hardware system. There are several procedures inside this script that need to access constants outside the procedures. At the moment every procedure uses `upvar` keyword to basically enable the procedure to access the constants declared outside it. However, this seems to clutter the code. Is there any other way that the procedures can access the constants outside it that do not use `upvar` and do not clutter the code as well? Is declaring them as global the only other way?

Different procedures share same constants, so I cannot just put them inside the procedures themself.

Answer (score 2):

Any variable declared as `global` is in the global namespace and can be
accessed using the `::` prefix.

```
proc a { } {
   global va
   set va aa
}

a
puts $::va
```

Variables declared within a namespace can be access by prefixing the variable
with the namespace.

```
namespace eval nn { 
  variable nnb

  proc init {} {
     variable nnb
     set nnb bb
  }

  init
}

puts $::nn::nnb
```

Essentially, any variable that is not a local variable is part of a namespace,
the global namespace (`::`) or some other namespace and can be accessed with
the fully qualified variable name.

To avoid clutter, you can also use arrays to hold constants and variables.
I find a single `variable vars` much easier to work with than a very long list
of `global` declarations.

```
 set const(pi) 3.14151927
 set const(unary) 1
 set const(nil) 0

 proc mydebug { } {
    puts $::const(pi)
 }
```

or

```
 proc mydebug { } {
    global const
    puts $const(pi)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

See Brad Lanam's answer for most of what I would have otherwise said.

---

If you have a lot of constants, put them in the global array with the empty name.

```
# Initialise constants
array set {} {
    pi 3.141
    e  2.718
}
```

Then you can access them all from a procedure like this:

```
proc calculate {x} {
    global {};  # Bring the constants into visibility
    return [expr {$(pi) * $(e) ** $x}]
}
```

This keeps using a constant relatively low on syntax.